# Bash script not searching a given directory

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

So I'm trying to write a script that searches a directory given by the user for all the files of a specific extension that is also provided by the user. So far my script is only searching the mybooks directory of my home folder no matter what directory is given. The script so far looks like this:

```
# Prompts the user to input a directory
# Saves input in variable dir
echo -n "Please enter a directory to search in: "
read dir
if [ ! -d /$dir ]; then
   echo "You didn't enter a valid directory path. Please try again."
fi

# Prompts the user to input a file extension to search for
# Saves input in variable ext
echo -n "Please enter a file extension to search for: "
read ext
echo "I will now search for files ending in "$ext

# Searches for files that match the given conditions and prints them
find $dir -type f -name $ext
for file in *$ext
do
echo $file
done

#TODO: put code here that prints the names of the largest and smallest files
# that were found in the search

echo "The largest file was: "
echo "The smallest file was: "
```

So you can see that the mybooks directory is never provided. Here is example output:

```
Please enter a directory to search in: /var/books
Please enter a file extension to search for: .txt
I will now search for files ending in .txt
hound.txt
list-lines.txt
numbers.txt
The largest file was: 
The smallest file was: 
$ls /var/books/
arthur-conan-doyle_The-hound-of-baskervilles.txt  arthur-conan-doyle_The-valley-of-fear.txt  mary-roberts-rinehart_The-circular-staircase.txt
arthur-conan-doyle_The-hound-of-baskervilles.zip  arthur-conan-doyle_The-valley-of-fear.zip
```

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong or where to go from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
find $dir -type f -name $ext
for file in *$ext
do
echo $file
done
```

With this:

```
find "$dir" -type f -name "*.$ext"
```

#### Explanation

```
find $dir -type f -name $ext
```

The above searches `$dir` for files whose names are *exactly* `$ext`.  It is likely that there are no such files.

By contrast, the following ignores `$dir` and searches the current directory for files whose extension if `$ext`:

```
for file in *$ext
do
echo $file
done
```

Note that, because `$dir` or `$ext` might contain spaces or other difficult characters, they should be in double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! How would I then echo the results of the find command without ignoring $dir?

Comment: @MFonner By default, `find` will echo every name it finds.  I expect that `find $dir -type f -name $ext` echoed no names because there was no file whose name, in its entirety, matched `$ext`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I mis-typed a parameter.